# Can I put rendered component into flux store?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, flux, react-bootstrap

I try to create generic modal component for my application based on react-bootstrap Modal component.

The goal is to make it sole in the application, to have ability to exchange modal body without modal reopening, for example, for login/forget-pass/register forms.

I have modal-component in flux pattern with something like

```
export default class ModalComponent extends Component {
    handleMyFluxStoreChange() {
        this.setState({
            modalBody : this.modalStore.getModalBody(),
            modalShow: this.modalStore.getModalToggle()
        });
    }

    render() {

        <Modal show={this.state.modalShow}>
            {this.state.body}
        </Modal>
    }
}
```

This works great with scalars, but the question is:

**How should I put to modal body an entire component?**

Technically It's not a problem, I can do it like this in action creator

```
export const showLoginModal = () => {

    let modalBody = (<LoginModal />);

    AppDispatcher.dispatch({
        type: MODAL_CHANGE,
        payload: {
            body: modalBody
        }
    })
};
```

The question is Can I put rendered component to Store in flux, or flux store should keep only plain hashes?

What is a right way to do it in flux pattern?

Where should I render this component? Is action creator valid place for this?

Any read recommendation will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your store should really be limited to model-specific data. I would recommend keeping the component in the render function and then choosing how to render it based on a variable that is set in your store. Something like:

```js
export default class ModalComponent extends Component {

    handleMyFluxStoreChange() {
        this.setState({
            showLoginModal: this.modalStore.getLoginModalVisibility()
        });
    }

    render() {
        let modal;

        if (this.state.showLoginModal) {
           modal = <LoginModal />;
        }

        return modal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. With this aproach I will have to update modal-component for each new component which I want to render. I'm looking for solution to make it transparent in this aspect.

Comment: In that case, I can't really think of any other solution off the top of my head other than what you've implement

Answer (score 0):

Store is only used for state  of component.  In you case, you are passing the component itself to store which is not consider best practices in react flux.  Flux is based on emit event and dispatch action. Emit event if you want to create component dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. Where I should handle this event and create component to keep modal-component transparent?